# Not picking up dropped items

Tags: diablo-iii

As I am mashing the mouse button over and over again, is there a way to make it that my character DOES NOT pick up an item during an important boss battle, or any other battle for that matter? I find it sometimes difficult that my character goes out of his way to pick up a cheap sword during a battle (if I accidentally click on it), only to turn around and be bashed in the face from the boss.

I like the fact that gold is automatically picked up as you run over it, as opposed to the other 2 games, I also wish they did the same for other items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to go into the key bindings and set one of your keys to Move (it is unbound by default). That way when you press that key, your character will move to the location of your cursor without picking up items (or attacking).